# Autocomplete in Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, autocomplete

I have problems with the autocomplete in Django, Django recognize the autocomplete but it gets a 404 error when I try it

this is the part of the template I'm using the autocomplete

```
<table>
       <td class="input-group mb-3"><label for=" 
           {{TeacherForm.teacher.id_for_label}}"> Teacher(es):
            <td> <div class="ui-widget">
                {{TeacherForm.asesores}}</td>
             </div>
 </table>
```

This is my model:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastaname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

This is my form:

```
 class TeacherForm(forms.Form):
          teacher=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

This is the script I'm using:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#id_teacher").autocomplete({
         source: "/api/get_teacher/",
         select: function (event, ui) { //item selected
         AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
    },
      minLength: 2,
    });
  });

  function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
  {
    var selectedObj = ui.item;
   }

 </script>
```

This is my url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/get_teacher/', views.get_teacher, name='get_teacher'),

]
```

And in my view.py I have:

```
def get_teacher(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
       q = request.GET.get('term', '')    
       asesor = Asesor.objects.filter(lastname=q)     
       results = []
       for professor in teacher:
          teacher_json = {}
          teacher_json = professor.lastname+ " "+professor.firstname+" 
          "+professor.middlename
          results.append(teacher_json)
          data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
       data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

In my base_layout I'm calling:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<!-- jQuery UI !-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

When I try it, i get this error

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/get_teacher/?term=Guerrer 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I solve the error

Comment: can we see your root urls,? if you had called this urls file with 'include' from the `root urls`

Comment: `urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/filebrowser/', site.urls),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^inicio/',include('Search.urls')),
      
]` Search is the name op my app

Comment: what's the the name of the app containing your `api/get_teacher`

Comment: `api/get_teacher` is the url , I think. I search  code in order to do the autocompleate and i find like this

Comment: check my answer bellow

Comment: I do that, and i get the same error, but with inicio in it `jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/inicio/api/get_teacher/?term=Guerrer 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170869/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-ashmgm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `Search.urls` from the `root urls`, with the following

```
url(r'^inicio/',include('Search.urls')),
```

In that case, your url is not `/api/get_teacher/`, but instead a concatenation of the root `inicio/` + `api/get_teacher/`. The correct url is:

```
/inicio/api/get_teacher/
```

`

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the folder containing the file that has /api/get_teacher url?

Comment: @AshMGM Can you tell me the name of the folder containing the file that has /api/get_teacher url?

Comment: Yeas, the issue there was `inicio`. Without the whole url file, i couldn't see that you had another bug. glad it works